# Functional Analysis related to Hanh-Banach Theorem and Weak-* convergence.

Tags: functional-analysis

I am new here. I hope someone can help me with the case I am proving. I believe that this is basic to some so I will not include much detail. I just want to ask for some clue how to proceed on the proof.

I guess we have $E$ is separable since the prior results considers so.

Here it is: If $W$ is a weak-* closed linear subspace of $E^{*}$ and $f \in E^* \backslash W$,
then there exists $x \in E$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ but $g(x)=0$ for all $g\in W$.

Proving existence of $x\in E$ such that $f(x) \neq 0$ directly follows from the fact that $f \in E^*\backslash W$ and that $W$ is a subspace. My main problem is proving 'but $g(x)=0$ for all $g\in W$'.
Here are some results you may want to refer to:

1. The set $X^*$ is weakly-$\ast$ closed if every sequence $\{x_n^*\}_{n\in N}$ contained in $U^*$ converges weakly-$\ast$ to $x^* \in U^*$.
2. Let $X$ be a normed space. If $X$ is separable, then the closed unit ball $B_{X^*}$ in $X^*$ is weak-$\ast$ sequentially compact.
3. Let $X$ be a normed space, $U \subset X$ a closed subspace, and $x_0 \in X\backslash U$. Then
   there exists an $g\in X^*$ such that $g(x)=0$ for all $x\in U$ and $g(x_0)\neq 0$.

It would be really helpful even if you provide the slightest hint. Thank you very much.
P.S. I find it hard to encode things correct so here is an image of the above texts.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PIaoo.png)

Also, do you think using notion of isomorphism saying X/U isomorphic to X^*/U^* will work since we have J_X: X to X^** a canonical embedding so that we can use result #3 above?

Comment: This cannot be proved using  just 1), 2) and 3). You need  a more general form of Hahn-Banach Theorem. Rudin's FA book has this version.

Comment: I have that also as one of my references, unfortunately, although I have re-proven a number of Hanh-Banach related theorem, together with Banach-Alaoglu,  the closest approach is on Banach-Alaoglu, so I thought of using isomorphism since elements of dual of a dual of X can be interpreted as element of X. Also, The problem I am dealing with is a corollary on Function Analysis Appendix of 'A Course in Commutative Banach Algebras' below  Hanhn Banach Theorem, the 2 and 3 results, so I thought I am overthinking the case and may actually be very easy. Hence, my request for a hint. But thank you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Proving existence of $x∈E$ such that $f(x)≠0$ directly follows from the fact that $f∈E^∗\setminus W$
> and that $W$ is a subspace. My main problem is proving 'but $g(x)=0$
> for all $g∈W$'.

That's not how it works. You need to find $x$ satisfying both things simultaneously. If you get $f$ as you say, it might not be zero on $g$ and then you are stuck.

Separability of $E$ (which I'm assuming is a normed space though you don't say so) is irrelevant for your question.

Property 1 is the definition of weak$^*$-convergence, but it is stated wrongly because sequences are not enough and you need nets.

Property 2 is the adaptation of Banach-Alaoglu to the separable case (that allows you to use sequences instead of nets) but compactness of balls is irrelevant for your question.

Property 3 is the kind of property you want, but the weak$^*$-topology is not given by a norm, so this one is also irrelevant. And you are looking for an element of the **pre**-dual and not the dual.

$\def\Re{\operatorname{Re}}$
What you want to use here is the geometric/separation version of Hahn-Banach.  If you apply it to the weak$^*$-compact convex set $\{f\}$ and the weak$^*$-closed convex set $W$, there exists $\psi\in E^{**}$ and $c\in\mathbb R$ such that $$ \Re\psi(f)<c<\Re\psi(g),\qquad\qquad g\in W.$$ Because $W$ is a subspace this forces $\psi(g)=0$ for all $g\in W$ and $\psi(f)\ne0$.

To finish the question, you need the result that the dual of $(E^*, \text{weak}^*)$ is $E$. This means that for $\psi$ above there exists $x\in E$ such that $\psi(f)=f(x)$, $\psi(g)=g(x)$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your hint. I have rechecked how to utilized (Hanh- Banach,Separation) and the theorem after it in my reference(which is actually the theorem) you recommended to use. But following your steps, #3 will actually work if instead of closed, we have weak* closed, is this correct( just the thought process)? Also can we readily say those descriptions of set  $\{f\}$ and not use Banach-Alaoglu?

Comment: No, #3 is for normed spaces, and $(E^*,\text{weak}^*)$ is not a normed space unless $\dim E <\infty$. For your second question, you need no theorems to say that a singleton is compact.

Comment: Oh. I thought it is all of $f$. It is clear now.  Wow. Thank you very much. Although I have to (re)prove the geometric/separation version where X is not necessarily normed space. My mistake was... I am still at separation version wherein the larger set $X$ is a normed space. In Rudin, indeed the the condition to use the theorem fits this(the case you presented) case.